# How do I see the source tables that Infor XA Power-Link is using to create the current view?

Tags: sql

Through Infor XA Power-Link, I have access to a sales history view with things like quantity, price, item number, etc.

Using System i Navigator, I would like to be able to run a SQL script that produces a similar table, but customized to my liking.

However, I'm having trouble locating the tables involved in producing the Power-Link view. Is there a way to check the source using Power-Link so that I can get the table names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure is!  You need to use the SQL Monitor.  Start the business object and go to Help then About Infor.  The about screen will appear.  Hit Control-D to start the SQL Monitor.  You should see 3 columns:  Start, Duration and SQL.  Refresh the view and see the SQL Monitor will populate.  Right-click and copy the entry that has 'SQL SW executeQuery' entry and paste into your favorite SQL editor.  This will be the exact SQL select statement used by PowerLink.  Modify to your needs.

Let me know if you need anything else.

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Note: You can prevent users from accessing any of the Diagnostic tools which includes the SQL monitor. This is done via security task DSPDGNINF. It's located under the CAS application > Client System Preferences security area.

Load menu AMZM38 - CAS Security Maintenance
Select Option 1 Area and task authorizations
Select CAS as the application
Use Option 2 Change on Client System Preferences security area
Use Option 11 Authorize users to configure who should have access and who should not (revoke)
F12 to go back one screen
Lock task DSPDGNINF

Please note, security is not active until the task is locked. Also, to test, one must use a new Power-Link session as security is cached.